# CSS 'nth-of-type' and 'first-of-type Selectors' - Good Practice/Tidier Code

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am currently using this CSS selector:

```
td:nth-of-type(2),td:nth-of-type(3),
td:nth-of-type(4),td:nth-of-type(5),
td:nth-of-type(6),td:nth-of-type(7),
td:nth-of-type(8),td:nth-of-type(9),
td:nth-of-type(10){
    /* CSS rules... */
}
```

I want to apply the rules to columns 2-10 and I would rather say if its NOT column 1 the do `{}`

What is a better way to do this and is it possible to cut the code down to become more readable and concise?

The logic would like is:

```
if column number is not 1 then
    do some code
else    
    do something else
```

Comment: More "user friendly"? :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely cut down quite a bit on the clutter:

```
td { /* "not 1" */
    /*
       Of course this applies to the first column as well
       but you can override it with the next rule just below.
    */
}

td:not(:first-of-type) { /* more pure alternative for the above */ }

td:first-of-type { /* "1" */ }
```

Keep in mind that `<td>` does not equal "column", as columns may also be `<th>`s and in addition the `colspan` attribute can make an element take up multiple columns.

You can also use this effectively equivalent version that has extremely broad browser compatibility (includes IE >= 7):

```
td:first-child { /* "1" */ }

td { /* "not 1" */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are specifically targeting entire column 1 (Assuming you are not using `th` here so)

```
table tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
   /* Target 1st column */
   /* First td in each tr will be targeted here, and being more specific, 
      it will over ride the element selector defined below for each td element */
}

table tr td {
   /* Styles For The Rest */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-of-type(n+2)` notation. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2kBVh/2/)

See http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type